# implode array with custom format

Tags: php, implode

I have this form of array

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 8
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 10
        [3] => 11
        [4] => 19
        [5] => 13
        [6] => 10
    )
```

I want to implode the value to this form `[0,8],[1,2],[2,3],[3,11],[4,19],[5,13],[6,10]`. Is there any builtin php function to do this?

Comment: NO, there is not a built in function to perform this task.

Comment: The output is in a form of a string, right?

Answer (score 3):

```
$out = array();
foreach($array as $k => $v) {array_push($out, array($k, $v)); }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$new_arr = array_map(null, array_keys($arr), $arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines :

```
$array = array ( '0' => 8, '1' => 2, '2' => 10, '3' => 11, '4' => 19, '5' => 13, '6' => 10 );

$tempArray = array();
foreach( $array as $key => $value )
{
    $tempArray[] = '[' .$key .',' .$value .']';
}

$imploded = implode( ',' , $tempArray );

echo $imploded;
```

> Output :

```
[0,8],[1,2],[2,10],[3,11],[4,19],[5,13],[6,10]
```

Answer (score 0):

You ask about any built in PHP function for your need, then the answer it doesn't ( ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php ).

Even if it only needs 3 lines of code ...

```
$result = array();
while (list($key, $value) = each($your_array)) {
    $result[] = array($key, $value);
}
```